# Waitable timer not waiting for specified time period

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, msdn

I am creating a manual waitable timer as following

```
m_hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, true, NULL);
```

And using it in a function

```
HRESULT ClassA::InduceSleep(UINT32 uiMiliSeconds)
{
    if (m_hTimer)
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;
        liDueTime.QuadPart = (uiMiliSeconds) * (-10000) * (1LL);
        if (!SetWaitableTimer(m_hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0))
        {
            Log("SetWaitableTimer failed GLE[%d]", GetLastError());
            goto exit;
        }

        // Wait for the timer.

        if (WaitForSingleObject(m_hTimer, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            Log("WaitForSingleObject failed GLE[%d]", GetLastError());
        }
        return S_OK;
    }
exit:    
    Sleep(uiMiliSeconds);
    return S_OK;
}
```

I am observing that on calling InduceSleep() with delay for 10 seconds(or 5 seconds) the waitforsingleobject is returning WAIT_OBJECT_0 immediately without any delay, so the timer is signalled immediately. It is mentioned in the documentation that setwaitable timer stops and re-activate the timer so it should not be in signalled state and should be signaled only after the given time. What am I missing here?

Comment: Out of curiosity (but probably off-topic): Why `(-10000) * (1LL)`? Why not `-10000LL`? What is the value of `uiMilliSeconds` you call your function with?

Comment: Btw. The question about `(-10000) * (1LL)` was not that bad. ;-) `LL` makes a `long long` constant which has more bytes than `UINT32`. This had reversed the type promotion and resulted in a `long long` multiplication (`uiMiliseconds * -10000LL`) i.e. converted the `uiMiliSeconds` to `long long` and solved your issue as well.

Comment: we need `liDueTime.QuadPart = (LONGLONG)uiMiliSeconds * -10000LL` code - first `uiMiliSeconds` must be expanded to 64 bit (it will be zero expanded because `uiMiliSeconds` is unsigned and this is ok) and then mult on `-10000LL` (`0xFFFFFFFFFFFFD8F0`). in your code you mult UINT32 on `FFFFD8F0h` (`-10000`) and got very small **postivive** value - absolute time near 1600 year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple error:

`uiMiliSeconds` is of type `UINT32` i.e. an unsigned type.

This makes

```
(uiMiliSeconds) * (-10000)
```

an unsigned multiplication i.e. `-10000` is converted to `unsigned` before multiplication. (I agree, type promotion is sometimes a tricky topic.)

I tried this in a minimal sample:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  uint32_t uiMilliseconds = 10 * 1000;
  std::cout << uiMilliseconds * -10000 << '\n';
  std::cout << (int)uiMilliseconds * -10000 << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4194967296
-100000000
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b23a8e60be7365c6)</kbd>

So, the solution is to simply convert `uiMiliseconds` to a signed integer before multiplication (as I did in the second output line).

The rest of the story is probably obvious to OP. From MSDN about [SetWaitableTimer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer):

> `lpDueTime`
>
> The time after which the state of the timer is to be set to signaled, in 100 nanosecond intervals. Use the format described by the FILETIME structure. Positive values indicate absolute time. Be sure to use a UTC-based absolute time, as the system uses UTC-based time internally. Negative values indicate relative time.

So, the wrong computed time seems to yield a value which is already in the past. This is the only reasonable explanation why the `SetWaitableTimer(m_hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0)` returns immediately. (OP checked for error and didn't recognize one.)

---

To make it "bullet-proof", I would recommend

```
 uiMiliSeconds * -10000LL
```

considering that e.g. VC uses 32 bits for `int` (even for x64). So, due to type promotion, any `UINT32` value would expand to the corresponding `long long` without the danger of overflow.

---

RbMm complained that type `UINT32` for `MiliSeconds` might be a not-so-lucky choice as it covers only a sub-range of times which can be set. In the case of OP, this sub-range might be sufficient. Otherwise, type `UINT64` might be considered.

Comment: really need **unsigned expand** `uiMiliseconds` to a 64 bit before multiple : `(unsigned __int64)uiMiliseconds * -1000`

Comment: the final result is 64bit value. if first argument of multiple expression will be 32bit (signed or unsigned does not matter) we can got overflow begin form some value

Comment: @RbMm In general, you are right. In the specific issue of OP with 5 or 10 seconds, this is at most 10000 * -10000. Hence, the overflow wasn' t the issue here.

Comment: yes, we need negative value. but i say about another, if wait interval will be big - we got overlow if not expand it first to 64 bit